# Back button when reloadOnSearch:false

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got `ngView` with three `ngIncluded` views: search filters, products, pagination. I want to:

1. filter products without reloading whole page just products view
2. add filters to the url eg. `?category=shoes`
3. be able to use back and next buttons

I set `reloadOnSearch: false` in `$routeProvier.when`. Now when I invoke `$location.search()` function url changes, but the page is not reloaded. That's what I wanted to achieve, but when I click back button the products does not reload to its previous state. The only thing which happens is a change of url. The question is how can I handle back and next button events in this situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do reloadOnSearch:false, the same instance of the controller is used and any back forward does not reload any controller or related view. You need to respond to `$routeUpdate` event that gets raised in such scenarios. See $route [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route) regarding this.

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate',function(e) {
   // Code to handle the route change.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle everything manually. It means that when you press the back or the next button you have to get back to the state you where using the $location.